# ListPicker separate templates for Normal and Expanded states

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

Is is possible to either subscribe to a ModeChanged event or to have a separate template for the Normal and Expanded states of the ListPicker control.

I am specifically looking for a way to have my text wrapped when the ListPicker is expanded (not full-screen) and not wrapped when the ListPicker is in the Normal state.

I am using this in a Windows Phone 7.1 targeted application and the GotFocus, LostFocus, and Tap events are not being fired.  Right now, the only event I can look at is the SizeChanged event to look at switching templates by looking at the ListPickerMode status.

Answer (score 2):

The ListPicker supports 2 separate templates, one for each scenario.

Use `ItemTemplate` for the expanded view.
Use `FullModeItemTemplate` for the full page view.

Comment: ItemTemplate is for BOTH the ExpanededView and the Normal view, lPicker.ListPickerMode is (ListPickerMode.Normal or ListPickerMode.Expanded).  I am looking for a way to display the short list with TextWrapping when I have less than 5 items in the list and not have to open the FullMode window for a short list.